Omni-channel Flow handle decline and a list of users
I have an Omni-Channel Flow as a subflow on a custom object.
When criteria is met in the parent Flow to fire this Omni-Channel Flow, it runs an invocable apex method that parses a field on the custom object that will be populated with JSON that looks like this:
[{"Order" : 1, "Name" : "Charlotte Hale"}, {"Order" : 2, "Name" : "Wade Wilson"}, {"Order" : 3, "Name" : "Jin Sakai"}]

My invocable apex then returns a list of user ids I want to route a Case to, the ids are ordered by the "Order" attribute in the JSON above.
The loop in this flow will loop through this list of user ids and runs the Check Availability for Routing tool to see which user is available first. Once a user id is available, the Route Work tool will route the Case to that user id.
My questions are:

Can omni-channel flows handle when a user declines work?
If a user declines, is there a way to ignore the routing configuration and route to the next user in my list of user ids?

Thank you!

